# I am getting dependency errors when building my Ionic app

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, native, capacitor

I am building a simple Capacitor Ionic app that uses geolocation. When I run `ionic capacitor build ios`I get the following errors in the commandline:

**Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "CapacitorGeolocation":
In Podfile:
CapacitorGeolocation (from `../../node_modules/@capacitor/geolocation`)
Specs satisfying the `CapacitorGeolocation (from` ../../node_modules/@capacitor/geolocation`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.**

I am running:

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.10
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.10
@angular/cli                  : 11.2.10
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.7
@capacitor/core : 2.4.7

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's a versions compatibility issue. You'll have to upgrade/downgrade one of them. [Read this](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started/dependencies)

Comment: I fixed this problem downgrading the `@capacitor/ios`. I had v. 3.0.0 and after downgrading to 2.4.7 the problem disappeared. I did that changing the version in `package.json`